# Change default Payara debug port via asadmin

Tags: debugging, remote-debugging, payara

Is there a way to configure Payara, via asadmin, to use another port for its debug?
The port 9009 is conflicting with a local service, that I cannot stop.

I tried the command:

```
asadmin set java.debugger.port=19009
```

found [here](https://blog.payara.fish/administering-payara-server-5-with-the-cli), but Payara is still starting with debug on port 9009.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by setting the specific `java-config` options. For example (Payara needs to be running):

`asadmin get server.java-config.debug-options` should yield something like:

```
server.java-config.debug-options=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9009
```

Then you simply need to replace the port, e.g. like so:

```
asadmin set server.java-config.debug-options=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=19009
```

Then start Payara in debug mode and you should be set:

```
asadmin start-domain --debug true <domain name>
```